# Trying to change mail compose navigation bar text colour

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the colour of the navigation bar text for the email compose view which I previously had working, however since I have changed the size and font of the navigation bar text throughout the app, this has broken my code.

I have this code in the view controller that segues to the view controller that contains the email button:

```
    var attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 24)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

This is the code I was previously using to change the navigation bar colour to white:

```
    mc.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

I have this code in viewDidLoad in one of my view controllers, but it doesn't affect the mail compose view controller:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

mailCnt.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor
should work

Comment: That's what I've tried, but it doesn't work with the modified font.